# If: Badly formed number when using less then sign

Tags: csh

I am totally new to CSH, so I apologize if this is a trivial question. I have a variable called "accuracy" which I read from a file and I want to compare it to some other value. Here is a bit of the code:

```
set accuracy = `cat results.dat | tail -1 | cut -c1-20`
echo '#####ACCURACY: '$accuracy
set solved = 0
if ($accuracy <= 0.000000008) set solved = 1
```

If I do this I get this error

> if: Badly formed number.

However if I replace the last line with this:

```
if ( $accuracy == 0.000000000000) set solved = 1
```

Everything works fine. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? The output of the first echo is this:

> ACCURACY: 0.000000000007

Comment: Bash doesn't support floating-point math *at all* -- and moreover, `(` doesn't work as test syntax (the use mode of the `test` command that *resembles* shell-language syntax is `[`).

Comment: Morevore, `set solved = 0` *does not* define a variable `solved`; instead, it changes `$1` to `solved`, `$2` to `=`, and `$3` to `0`. I wonder if your shell isn't actually bash?

Comment: Thank you! So why is the second version working?

Comment: The second version *doesn't* work.

Comment: See it running, with a log, on the online interpreter at https://ideone.com/WL2Hl6 (I had to set a specific value in place of your pipeline, since of course the sandbox has no `results.dat` file). You'll see that there's no numeric value for `accuracy` echoed, and the `if` command at the end just throws an error.

Comment: Maybe your actual shell is csh-family (and not bash at all)? *That* one uses the `set` keyword for variable assignments.

Comment: So there is no way to do what I want in bash?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes it is csh... sorry, I am really not good at this

Comment: BTW, this is a somewhat different scenario here because the only answer was tagged community wiki (disowning personal credit), but *usually* we frown on editing questions in a way that invalidates existing answers, and suggest asking a new/different question instead.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a bash script at all -- it's a csh script. A bash version might look like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
accuracy=$(tail -1 <results.dat | cut -c1-20)
echo "#####ACCURACY: $accuracy"
solved=0
if [[ $(bc <<<"$accuracy <= 0.000000008") = 1 ]]; then
  solved=1
fi
```

See [BashFAQ #22](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/022) for a discussion of doing floating-point math in bash.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I realized later it is a csh (I am really new to this so I wasn't even aware of the difference). However, the code I am using is much longer than the 3 lines I pasted here, so I can't really turn it all to bash. Is there a way to do the "$accuracy <= 0.000000008" part in csh?

Comment: I don't know csh (and don't advise learning or using it; see http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt and http://www.memoryhole.net/~kyle/csh.whynot.txt), so can't help you there. A separate question tagged only for csh might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that csh does not support floating points in an Expression, only integers.

```
set accuracy = `cat results.dat | tail -1 | cut -c1-20`
echo '#####ACCURACY: '$accuracy
set solved = 0
if (`echo "$accuracy <= 0.000000008" | bc`) set solved = 1
```

For more complicated expressions one may want to use `bc -l` rather than plain `bc`. With `-l` things like `e(x)` and `l(y)`, which implement e<sup>x</sup> and ln(y) respectively (and many more).

**Note**: As many have mentioned, you should avoid using csh. Despite having contributed small changes to tcsh, I have stopped using it once I read [CSH Programming Considered Harmful](http://www.memoryhole.net/~kyle/csh.whynot.txt).